# Accessing Results of CURL request + PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm executing a curl request using php:

```
  //Initiate cURL.
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  //Encode the array into JSON.
  $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($data);

  //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

  //Set the content type to application/json
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

  //Execute the request
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The browser returns:

```
{"success":"true","lead_id":"141872","code":201}

OR

{"error":true,"duplicate":true,"message":"Duplicate: This has already been submitted to the API.","code":400}
```

How do I access the data in $result it current only returns 1

Answer (score 2):

Set return transfer to true to get the page response in $result

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array (
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 1, // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1, // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1 ,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("REMOTE_ADDR: $proxy", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $proxy"),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url 
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

your solution :